# What Does The Notation of Union Over K represent?

Tags: notation, mathematical-foundations

I am currently studying about polynomial time in Comp Theory. The definition for polynomial time given in my textbook as follows:
$$P= \bigcup_{k}TIME(n^k)$$
I have not seen the **Union over k** notation before. K is a constant. A quick introduction to the meaning of this notation would be enormously helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Simple: $k$ is *not* a constant here. It's a bound variable.

Comment: This is a good question! That notation is indeed confusing, especially if this is the first time you see it. As the other comments/answers say, it is a shorthand for $\cup_{k=1}^\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authors often leave out the domain of the union if it is clear within the context. Here, $k$ is a natural number, i.e. $P = \bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} TIME(n^k) $. This is what it means for a complexity function to be bounded by a polynomial: there is a constant $k$ such that the function is in $\mathcal{O}(n^k)$.

Comment: (Also, the result will be the same in this case if k ranges over the integers, or the rationals, or the reals, or the positive rationals, or the positive reals. ​ (or, for that matter, the primes, etc.)) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: So its the domain of the union. Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @PenguinsAndApples No, not the domain; that's $\mathbb{N}$. It's a bound variable.